# Change Date Format in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, format

Hi i am getting the date value from the **database** with the following

> {{request.user.date_joined}}

in the following format  `
 **Jan. 14, 2011, 6:40 a.m**
and  i need to change the format like this 
 **2012-08-24 00:26:44**
please tell me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the date filter

```
{{ request.user.date_joined|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s" }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date

Comment: just wondering, would changing the `DATE_FORMAT` setting in settings.py refect this change all over the project?

Comment: Close, you'd want to set `DATETIME_FORMAT` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_FORMAT

Answer (score 3):

You can use `date` filters

```
{{ request.user.date_joined |date:"D d M Y" }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date